# JSON sort by value jQuery or JS

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, sorting

before tagging this duplicate please know I tried every possible answers here.

am getting output like this,
[image]

I tried these,

```js
var jsonObjSeat = jQuery.parseJSON(seatJson);

//jsonObjSeat.sort(function (a, b) {
//    return a.seats.number.localeCompare(b.seats.number);
//});

function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

people = sortByKey(jsonObjSeat, 'seats.number');
```

I needed 1A,1C..2A,2C ..etc

fiddle here,
https://jsfiddle.net/h9548dLc/8/

Comment: add your json also

Comment: added fiddle above , if you missed it , here https://jsfiddle.net/h9548dLc/8/

Comment: @sajanyamaha, your `number` field of `seats` object is a string. And in a string the value `"10"` is lesser than `"2"`.

Comment: ok @Rai maybe I can split and convert it to number and then sort , but what about the alphabets sort ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha, I'm not really that experienced in javascript buddy. But logically speaking, you could probably do this: use `sort()` twice. *(i)*after applying split, sort based on the number part. *(ii)*use the list obtained in *(i)* and apply sort based on the alphabets. I don't know if there's any direct function for alphanumeric sort, but this I feel can be a temporary one until someone who knows better gives an answer worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localeCompare(compareString[, locales[, options]])` with options `{numeric: true}`.

```
function sortBySeat(array) {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.seats.number.localeCompare(b.seats.number, 'en', {
      numeric: true
    });
  });
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/jpm9Ldr7/8/)

MDN Web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)